# Mongrel cluster returning page source

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby, ruby-on-rails, mongrel, mongrel-rails

I've setup a mongrel_rails cluster which worked correctly until I decided to reinstall ruby/rails/mongrel.

I'm able to get an output when I visit the website, but I'm obtaining the page source instead of a parsed html file...

From what I understand, the returned header is incorrect:

```
Date: Sat, 28 Aug 2010 17:19:21 GMT
Content-Length: 17374
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain

200 OK
```

when I should receive something like (returned by a thin instance)

```
Date: Sat, 28 Aug 2010 17:20:32 GMT
Server: thin 1.2.7 codename No Hup
Etag: "48db41ed4b0969cd6239c36dec57198d"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Runtime: 1483
Content-Length: 5250
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate

200 OK
```

Is there any setting in mongrel/apache (mongrel is behind a proxy) I should modify to fix this?

Relevant gems installed version:
mongrel (1.1.5)
mongrel_cluster (1.0.5)
rails (2.3.8, 2.3.5)
thin (1.2.7)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a solution provided @ https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4690.

Given by Matthew Denner June 25th, 2010 @ 12:15 PM

By adding the following two lines (to lib/mongrel/cgi.rb, around line 80):

```
@head['cookie'] = options['cookie'] if options['cookie']
options.delete('cookie')
```

before:

```
REMOVED_KEYS.each {|k| options.delete(k) }
```